# Error converting bytecode to dex-Android

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-multidex

Using the following dependencies

```
'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.4'
'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Top-level build file

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
```

Gradle version 4.0

Android Studio 3.0 Canary4

Getting the following error on running the app

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzg;
Error:com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzg;
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:608)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:563)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:545)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:167)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:194)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.mergeDexes(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:66)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:54)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:37)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzg;
Information:BUILD FAILED in 16s
Information:16 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Please help.

Comment: One (or more) of your dependencies use a Firebase dependency with a different version.

Comment: Thanks @GergelyKőrössy, i was mixing versions 10.2.4 and 11.0.1, it works now.

Comment: No problem. Should I add it as an answer then?

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy, Yep, go ahead.

Answer (score 2):

This error happens when two dependencies use the same dependency with different version numbers. In this case one of your dependencies use a Firebase one with a different version.

You can check your dependency tree by running `gradle app:dependencies` (or if you have a wrapper which is usually the case for Android Studio projects, `gradlew app:dependencies`) where `app` is the module's name you want to check.

Comment: Thank you @Gergely Kőrössy, that was exactly my mistake

Comment: @Geob could you please accept the answer if it worked for you?